# Direct vs. Indirect Objects

Tags: grammar, objects, direct-objects, indirect-objects

I would like to check my work identifying the direct and, if applicable, indirect objects in the following sentences.

1. The kid threw the textbook. ('the textbook' here is a direct object, correct?)
2. The teacher gave the students homework. ('the students' would be the direct object and 'homework' would be the indirect object here?)
3. His sister called him a genius. (what would 'him' be considered here?)

Comment: The teacher gave homework [to] the students - s/he didn't give the students to anyone!

Answer (score 0):

The OP has correctly identified the direct object *textbook* in (1).

In (2),  *homework* is the direct object, and *the students* is the indirect object.

In (3), *him* is the direct object.  Please note that *genius* is the object complement.